# Determining if the first string starts with second string

Tags: shell, test

JavaScript has a function for this:

```
'world'.startsWith('w')
true
```

How can I test this with shell? I have this code:

```
if [ world = w ]
then
  echo true
else
  echo false
fi
```

but it fails because it is testing for equality. I would prefer using a builtin,
but any utilities from this page would be acceptable:

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/idx/utilities.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set a variable to that value (here we set `$str` to `world`):

```
str=world
```

Then:

```
if [ -n "${str%%w*}" ]
then
  echo false
else
  echo true
fi
```

1. Aggressively remove the pattern `w*` from the start of `$str`.  `w*` matches `w` followed by any number of characters, so it'll match the whole string if possible.
2. If anything is left, then `$str` does not start with `w`.

Or:

```
if [ "$str" = "${str#w}" ]
then
  echo false
else
  echo true
fi
```

1. Remove `w` from `$str`, if possible.
2. Compare with `$str`.
3. If equal (i.e. the removal did nothing), then `$str` does not start with `w`.

Comment: The first code snippet does not work if str is already empty.

Answer (score 12):

If your shell is bash: within double brackets, the right-hand side of the == operator is a pattern unless fully quoted:

```
if [[ world == w* ]]; then
    echo true
else
    echo false
fi
```

Or more tersely: `[[ world == w* ]] && echo true || echo false` [*]

If you are not targetting bash specifically: use the case statement for pattern matching

```
case "world" in
    w*) echo true ;;
    *)  echo false ;;
esac
```

[*] but you need to be careful with the `A && B || C` form because `C` will be executed if **either** A fails **or** B fails. The `if A; then B; else C; fi` form will *only* execute C if A fails.

Answer (score 3):

The standard `sh` syntax for that is with a `case` construct:

```
string=world
start=w
case $string in
  ("$start"*) printf '%s\n' "$string starts with $start";;
  (*)         printf '%s\n' "$string does not start with $start";;
esac
```

Note the quotes around `$start` which are necessary in the cases where `$start` contains wildcard characters. For instance, with `start='*'`, without them, `$start*` would always match. Same goes for the `[[ $string = "$start"* ]]` of ksh/bash.